# Hide div from the loaded php file

Tags: php, ajax

I have a div on a page that loads a PHP file into it using Ajax when a user clicks on a link.  This works fine, but what I would like to do is have an `onclick` event in the loaded PHP file to be able to hide the same div on the page.

Comment: After your AJAX call completes, just set the `div` to `display: none;` with Javascript.

Comment: If the PHP file is not inside an iFrame JavaScript events will still work as normal when they are loaded into the div using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to hide the div with a button that is loaded into the div via ajax.

You can make use of `.on` for this.

In you ajax file add a `button` with a class of `close`

`<button class="close">Close</button>`

In your page making the request add this bit of jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', 'button.close', function(){
        $(this).parents('div').hide();
    });

});
```

Obviously you may need to alter the selector in the .parents() call to match your parent div, you could always add a class to the div and target that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
1. Add a button or link in loaded php file content
2. Write a onclick event to hide the div
3. As the php file content is loaded through AJAX, it will not bind to document, 
   So you need to use on or delegate function of jQuery to work it properly
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Just write some corresponding javascript in your loaded php file. For example:

Your HTML before calling ajax:

```
<div id="my_container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //using jQuery
    $("#hide_parent").live('click', function(){
        $("my_container").hide();
    });
</script>
```

In your php script:

```
<a href="#" id="hide_parent">Hide me away</a>
```

Comment: This `$("#hide_parent").click` will not work here as it is dynamically added content.

Comment: Even `live` is deprecated, use `on` or `delegate`